# Which applications are developer environments and operating systems coded in?

Tags: android, ios, windows, visual-studio

I have been wondering about this for a while.

What applications is programs like visual studio programmed in? But also, where is operating systems like android, ios and windows written in?

I just find it hard to imagine how developer environments are/were made, when they didn't exist! Get me right, I know that other developer environments probably existed at the time that they were made. But which?
There is probably some logical explanation to this, and I would be happy to get to know it!

Comment: See [The Chicken and Egg Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)#The_chicken_and_egg_problem), and then read rest of that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Programs and OSs are typically written in programming languages, not "applications", whatever that means.

Comment: Maybe a clarification of the question title would help: "What applications were used to build developer environments and operating systems?"

Comment: This is a reasonable question. When you realize you've been using hammers to make hammers you start to wonder how it all started. You end up either talking about evolution or Genesis.

Comment: See [Bootstrapping - Software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Software_development). Compilers for a new language are often written in a previous language, and at some point re-written in their own language, so that you can use an older version of the same compiler to compile a newer one.

Answer (score 4):

New is made from old.

iOS was developped on Macs and first Macintosh software was programmed on Apple II computers.

At the beginning, programming was like that (picture from: [70 years ago, six Philly women became the world's first digital computer programmers](http://www.phillyvoice.com/70-years-ago-six-philly-women-eniac-digital-computer-programmers/)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An [Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is mostly a glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), also able to run external programs like compilers, debuggers, and version control systems. Good enough editors (like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) are able to play all the roles of an IDE (completion, running compilers, debuggers, etc).

An editor (including IDEs) is today a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application. In the past it could have been a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) based application.

Today, GUI applications are written above [widget toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) (like [Qt](http://q.io/), [GTK](http://gtk.org/), etc.) and communicate with some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server). Terminal applications often use a terminal handling library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Compilers are "just" big command line programs transforming a file input (the source code) into a file output (the assembler or object code).

I'm surprised you have asked. A lot of IDEs and compilers (and operating systems and their utility) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and you can study their source code. Consider installing some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), it is mostly made of free software.